# Post Synthesis Simulation in QuestaSim

Tags: verilog, simulation, vivado, modelsim, questasim

I am attempting to perform post-synthesis simulation of a Verilog system designed in Vivado on QuestaSim. I am using QuestaSim 2021.2_1 and Vivado 2020.2. Here are the steps I have followed:

I generated a .v file containing the netlist of the complete design from Vivado using the command "write_verilog soc_top.v".

I generated a modelsim.ini file using the command "compile_simlib -simulator questa -family artix7 -language all -no_ip_compile -library unisim".

After importing two files into QuestaSim, one being soc_top.v and the second being tb_soc_top.v, I replaced the previously defined .ini file of ModelSim with the .ini file generated from step 2. After successful compilation, I encountered a list of errors on simulation such as:

Module 'VCC' is not defined.
Module 'OBUF' is not defined.

My assumption is that QuestaSim is unable to find the gate mapping after netlist generation.

Comment: What is your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the -no_ip_compile option.  You want the Xilinx IP which models Xilinx primitives like the OBUF.

Xilinx [UG900](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/46242?language=en_US) recommends doing it this way

Questa Advanced Simulator
"Generating a simulation library for Questa for all languages and for all libraries and all families in the current directory."

> compile_simlib -language all -simulator questa -library all -family all

Take a look at the the 'Preparing for Simulation' section of UG900, because there are different ways to compile the simulation libraries.

Using the -all option may compile more than you want.  You need the unisim libraries though to be able to simulate Xilinx privatives.

Make sure the files end up on your drives, located in the same place pointed to in the new generated.ini file.